# How to use VkLogicOp in vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I want to use VK_LOGIC_OP_XOR to implement a XOR operation, I've already set the logicOpEnable to VK_TRUE and enable the feature, but the result is still not correct.

```
VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment{};
colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;
colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_TRUE;
colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_DST_ALPHA;

VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending{};
colorBlending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
colorBlending.logicOpEnable = VK_TRUE;
colorBlending.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_XOR;
colorBlending.attachmentCount = 1;
colorBlending.pAttachments = &colorBlendAttachment;
colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;
```

What's the correct way to use this setting or did I miss something?

correct way to use VkLogicOp

Answer (score 0):

According to [OpenGL Logical Operation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Logical_Operation), I found this problem is caused by the SRGB image format. I changed the color attachment's format to VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM it works fine.